# Is there a way to transition from the end state of a CSS animation using transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I understand and use both transitions and animations, but it seems to me that there is a bit of a "hitch" as it were when trying to combine them. For example if you have an animation style that ends on a color, and sets the value indefinitely with `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` it would make a lot of sense if I could smoothly transition from this state to another one if an overriding style could be set.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7bh6x6k/). Note that toggling the yellow style uses the transition smoothly, but the use of animation can only smooth the initial 0-50% during the animation. There is no way to recover the final green state to either plain white or yellow background without an abrupt instant change that occurs when the animation value is unset. Note also that the animation, when active, completely overrides the `!important` style.

I don't know how much of this behavior is specified in the spec/WD/etc., but as far as I'm concerned this type of limiting behavior makes CSS animations next to worthless, and the animation would be advisable to perform step-wise from javascript, used with transitions. The downside to that is the greatly added overhead of doing it that way.

And to address the "unclear what I'm asking" vote, what I'm asking is how can I make an animation that can interpolate back out of the final animation state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, but have you tried use the value `reverse` in the `animation-direction` property for your animation?

Comment: You mean creating another animation that e.g. `0% { background-color: green } 100% {}`?  I hadn't considered that, and it seems inelegant, but I will use this...

Comment: Use of `reverse` is restricting; the same sequence would play in reverse. That is often not desired..... However I have gotten something that I like a lot better. See [new jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yt97wz13/). The only blemish here is that the "closing" animation plays upon pageload. Adding another class to use during toggle can help with this...

Comment: Interesting your solution, personally I've found useful the ´animation-duration: reverse´ showing & hiding a message keeping the same effect, besides I have had different behavior in certain animations in Firefox adding classes dinamically through javascript

Comment: Sure but what's the point of using animation at all if youre just going to have a single transition stage? Then just use transitions for that!

Comment: Surely I would use transition for simple animations, what I meant is keyframes are useful to create animations much more complex, and manipulate the transition step by step

Comment: Yeah but my point is that sometimes completely reversing the animation doesn't help at all. I can see how it might be perfect for many UI related purposes, though